# How to have one-time push in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a HTML widget with Laravel blade similar to the following (widget.blade.php):

```
@push('scripts')
   <script src="{{ asset('js/foo.js') }}"></script>
   <script>
   ...
   </script>
@endpush
@push('styles')
   <link href="{{ asset('css/bar.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush
<div>
... HTML contents
</div>
```

and I use the widget in an other blade like:

```
<div>
  ... 
  @include('widget')
</div>
<div>
  ... 
  @include('widget')
</div>
```

The problem is when I use the widget multiple times in a page the 'scripts' and 'styles' repeated multiple times.

How can I prevent Laravel to push 'scripts' and 'styles' multiple times?

Comment: Use `@yield` and `@section`

Comment: @aldrin27 Could you elaborate more or make me an example please?
NOTE: 'scripts' and 'styles' were use with other blades even the blades that include the widget

Comment: Based on my understanding you want to include the script files and your customized widget in all blades? Is it right?

Comment: @aldrin27 No. In that case, I will put my scripts and styles in master.blade

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**As of Laravel 7.25, Blade now includes a new @once component that will only render the items within the tags one time.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-once-directive**

In the following answer I assumed you are familiar with  [Blade extension](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#extending-blade). This method has been tested on Laravel 5.2 and 5.3 (See note below).

After testing [Ismail RBOUH's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135805/4003077) (so please read it), It seems there are two problems with the solution:

1- The $isDisplayed variable is not in a same scope with the other included widgets so each @include push its scripts to stack. As a result I change it to:

```
Blade::directive('pushonce', function ($expression) {
    $isDisplayed = '__pushonce_'.trim(substr($expression, 2, -2));
    return "<?php if(!isset(\$__env->{$isDisplayed})): \$__env->{$isDisplayed} = true; \$__env->startPush{$expression}; ?>";
});
Blade::directive('endpushonce', function ($expression) {
    return '<?php $__env->stopPush(); endif; ?>';
});
```

2- The solution limit the use of @pushonce to one widget. i.e. in the case of 2 or more widgets (widget1.blade.php, widget2.blade.php, ...) it prevent to push other widgets scripts. So, I add domain to @pushonce with the following code:

```
Blade::directive('pushonce', function ($expression) {
    $domain = explode(':', trim(substr($expression, 2, -2)));
    $push_name = $domain[0];
    $push_sub = $domain[1];
    $isDisplayed = '__pushonce_'.$push_name.'_'.$push_sub;
    return "<?php if(!isset(\$__env->{$isDisplayed})): \$__env->{$isDisplayed} = true; \$__env->startPush('{$push_name}'); ?>";
});
Blade::directive('endpushonce', function ($expression) {
    return '<?php $__env->stopPush(); endif; ?>';
});
```

**Usage:**

widget1.blade.php

```
@pushonce('scripts:widget1')
   <script src="{{ asset('js/foo.js') }}"></script>
   <script>
   ...
   </script>
@endpushonce
```

widget2.blade.php

```
@pushonce('scripts:widget2')
   <script src="{{ asset('js/bar.js') }}"></script>
   <script>
   ...
   </script>
@endpushonce
```

**NOTE FOR L 5.3:**
change the following line:

```
$domain = explode(':', trim(substr($expression, 2, -2)));
```

to

```
$domain = explode(':', trim(substr($expression, 1, -1)));
```

Comment: It's better to copy `@endpushonce` directive code to your answer. Otherwise it's a little confusing.

Answer (score 11):

This Works for me.

```
@once
    @push('page_scripts')
        <script type="text/javascript">
           
        </script>
    @endpush
@endonce
```

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to extend *Blade* by creating a `pushonce` directive as follows:

```
Blade::directive('pushonce', function ($expression) {

    $isDisplayed = '$__pushonce_'.trim(substr($expression, 2, -2));

    return "<?php if(!isset({$isDisplayed})): {$isDisplayed} = true; \$__env->startPush{$expression}; ?>";
});

Blade::directive('endpushonce', function ($expression) {

    return '<?php $__env->stopPush(); endif; ?>';
});
```

It must be added to `AppServiceProvider` `boot` method.

**Usage:**

```
@pushonce('scripts')
   <script src="{{ asset('js/foo.js') }}"></script>
   <script>
   ...
   </script>
@endpushonce

@pushonce('styles')
   <script src="{{ asset('js/foo.js') }}"></script>
   <script>
   ...
   </script>
@endpushonce
```

Please test it and let me know if that's help.

Comment: Thanks. The solution is **partially correct**. The correct one is too long and Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to comment it. So I added it as a new answer.

Comment: Okey. Good Luck    ;)

Comment: On line 3 `\$__env->startPush{$expression};` is wrong. I spent much time to understand why this is not working. But at the end I found your code is not correct. Please edit it as `\$__env->startPush({$expression});` . Add 2 parantheses.

Answer (score 3):

I've changed the code a bit:

```
Blade::directive('pushonce', function ($expression) {
    $var = '$__env->{"__pushonce_" . md5(__FILE__ . ":" . __LINE__)}';

    return "<?php if(!isset({$var})): {$var} = true; \$__env->startPush({$expression}); ?>";
});

Blade::directive('endpushonce', function ($expression) {
    return '<?php $__env->stopPush(); endif; ?>';
});
```

I'm using file and line number to set the variable, so can simply do:

```
@pushonce('scripts')
   Whatever
@endpushonce
```

Instead of:

```
@pushonce('scripts:widget1')
   Whatever
@endpushonce
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I don't have enough cred or something to reply to a comment above.

I recommend changing

```
$isDisplayed = '__pushonce_'.$push_name.'_'.$push_sub;
```

to

```
$isDisplayed = '__pushonce_' . md5($push_name.'_'.$push_sub);
```

because if your push looks like

```
@pushonce('after-styles')
```

PHP will not be happy with you because of the `_` in the string.

Comment: $push_sub = isset($domain[1]) ? $domain[1] : '';

Will also protect against not having "namespaced" push.

Answer (score 3):

[Appstract/laravel-blade-directives](https://github.com/appstract/laravel-blade-directives) provides an implementation of `@pushonce('scripts:widget')`, as well as other handy directives.

Just do `composer require appstract/laravel-blade-directives` and you're away.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tried `@once` with `@push` inside of it, but it just kept adding multiple instances of the script. This is the only thing that actually worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel 7.25.0 you can use `@once` blade directive.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/33812

Answer (score 0):

From v7.25 you can use the `@once` directive. Using this with `@push` and `@stack` will get what you want.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-once-directive

Example....

#### reveal.blade.php

```
<div>
   <h2 onclick="reveal(this)">{{$title}}</h2>
   <p class="hide">{{$text}}</p>
</div>

@once
@push('head.styles')
<style>
   .hide { display: none; }
</style>
@endpush
@endonce

@once
@push('body.scripts')
<script>
    window.reveal = function(element) {
        let nextElementStyle = element.nextElementSibling.style;
        nextElementStyle.display = nextElementStyle.display ==='block'?'none':'block';
    }
</script>
@endpush
@endonce
```

#### master.blade.php

```
<html>
   <head>
      @stack('head.styles')
   </head>
   <body>
      @include('reveal', ['title' => 'hello world', 'text'=>'This is some text'])
      @include('reveal', ['title' => 'hello world', 'text'=>'This is some text'])

      @stack('body.scripts')
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who struggling with @pushonce with variable passing this works for me Laravel 10

Add this to AppServiceProvider boot() method

```
     Blade::directive('pushonce', function ($expression) {
        return 
        "<?php 
            [\$pushName, \$pushSub] = explode(':', trim({$expression}));
            \$key = '__pushonce_'.str_replace('-', '_', \$pushName).'_'.str_replace('-', '_', \$pushSub);
            if(! isset(\$__env->\$key)): \$__env->{\$key} = 1; \$__env->startPush(\$pushName);
            echo isset(\$__env->\$key) == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no';
        ?>";
    });
    Blade::directive('endpushonce', function ($expression) {
        return '<?php $__env->stopPush(); endif; ?>';
    });
```

Usage blade:

```
$variable = 'modals:test';
@pushonce($variable)
```

Usage layout:

```
@stack('modals')
```

Comment: This answer isnt really relevant to this question.  If you wish you could post a new question and provide this answer yourself, this makes it easier for it to be useful to other stackoverflow users